# How does one calculate partial derivatives with two constant variables in statistical mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, differentiation

I came across this relation which I have yet to be able to prove or find proof of:
$$kT^2\left(\frac{\partial \ln\mathscr{Z}}{\partial T}\right)_{V,\mu}=\langle H\rangle-\mu\langle N\rangle$$
I was able to get it to:
$$\left(\frac{\partial \ln\mathscr{Z}}{\partial T}\right)_{V,\mu}=\left(\frac{\partial \ln\mathscr{Z}}{\partial T}\right)_{V,f}+\frac{\partial \ln\mathscr{Z}}{\partial T}$$
For context, $\mathscr{Z}$ is the grand canonical partition function and $f=e^{\frac{\mu}{kT}}$, making $f\equiv f(\mu)$.

I need help getting past this part since the final solution it yields is $\frac{\partial \ln\mathscr{Z}}{\partial T}=0$, which makes no sense knowing that $\ln\mathscr{Z}=\frac{PV}{kT}$.I tried calculating the derivatives via the only method I know:
$$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)_y=\frac{\partial (u,y)}{\partial (x,y)}$$
but I still keep getting the same $=0$ answer.

Giving further context:
$$\langle H\rangle=-\left(\frac{\partial \ln \mathscr{Z}}{\partial \beta}\right)_{f,V},\,\, \beta=\frac{1}{kT}$$
$$\langle N\rangle=kT\frac{\partial \ln\mathscr{Z}}{\partial\mu}$$

Edit: I had forgotten to write $\ln\mathscr{Z}$ instead of only $\mathscr{Z}$ in the first derivatives.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Thank you for your answer. I have the following expressions: $\mathscr{Z}=\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}f^NZ_N(V,T)$ and $Z_N(V,T)=\int\frac{dpdq}{N!h^{3N}}e^{-\beta H(p,q)}$.
I understand your answer to a certain extent, what I don't understand is how the two derivatives keeping variables constant are different from each other.

Comment: I've deleted the comment because I think it does not answer your question/ does not help much.

Comment: Ok, no problem.
I think I've narrowed my question to how is $\left(\frac{\partial \ln L}{\partial T}\right)_{V,\mu}$ different from $\left(\frac{\partial \ln L}{\partial T}\right)_{V,f}$ if $\frac{\partial}{\partial f}=\frac{kT}{f}\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}$, which isn't much of a difference.

Comment: One the other hand, if we say that $\mathscr{Z}\equiv\mathscr{Z}(V,f,\mu)$, then $d\mathscr{Z}=A dV+B df + C d\mu$. This means that the first term is $B$ and the second is $C$. How is then $B-C=\frac{\partial \mathscr{Z}}{\partial T}$?

Comment: Sorry, I think I cannot help here. I really don't understand the use of $f$. It seems that $f$ is a function of both $\mu$ and $T$, no? For me, it really just complicates things. What is the source/ reference of this calculation/ notation?

Comment: $f$ is what Huang called "fugacity" in his books. It is a function of $T$ and $\mu$ ($f=e^{\beta\mu}$). 
The source for this is my professor's own writing, it's one of his proposed exercises. He cites as bibliography Huang's Introduction to Statistical Physics and Statistical Mechanics, though I haven't been able to find this exercise or anything of the sort in any of the textbooks

Answer (score 4):

Once the fugacity $f$ is defined as $f=e^{\beta \mu}$ (with $\beta=1/k_BT$), $f$ becomes a function of $T$ and $\mu$. Therefore,
$$
\mathscr{Z}(T,V,f)=\mathscr{Z}(T,V,f(T,\mu))
$$
and the expression
$$\left(\frac{\partial \mathscr{Z}}{\partial T}\right)_{V,\mu}=\left(\frac{\partial \mathscr{Z}}{\partial T}\right)_{V,f}+\frac{\partial \mathscr{Z}}{\partial T}$$

is better written as
$$
\left(\frac{\partial \mathscr{Z}}{\partial T}\right)_{V,\mu}=\left(\frac{\partial \mathscr{Z}}{\partial T}\right)_{V,f}+\left( \frac{\partial \mathscr{Z}}{\partial f}\right)_{V,T}\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial T}  \right)_{\mu}\tag{1}
$$
From here, it is quite easy to get the result. Indeed,
$$
\mathscr{Z}={\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}} f^N Z_N(V,T)
$$
where $ Z_N(V,T)= \frac{1}{N!h^{3N}}\int d^{3N}qd^{3N}p ~~e^{-\frac{H(q,p)}{k_BT}}$ for classical systems (but a corresponding expression exists for quantum systems). Taking into account that the grand-canonical (GC) average of any observable $A$ can be written in terms of the corresponding canonical average (c) as
$$
\langle A \rangle_{GC}= \frac{1}{\mathscr{Z}}{\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}} f^N Z_N(V,T) \langle A \rangle_c,
$$
Equation $(1)$ can be divided bt ${\mathscr{Z}}$. Then, by using
$$\langle H\rangle=-\left(\frac{\partial \ln \mathscr{Z}}{\partial \beta}\right)_{f,V}=k_BT^2\left(\frac{\partial \ln \mathscr{Z}}{\partial T}\right)_{f,V},$$ and the two derivatives
$$\left( \frac{\partial \mathscr{Z}}{\partial f}\right)_{V,T}=
{\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}} N f^{N-1} Z_N(V,T)$$ and
$$
\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial T}  \right)_{\mu}=-\frac{\mu}{k_BT^2}f,
$$
we can easily obtain the required result.

An important thing to keep in mind when manipulating formulas in thermodynamics is that it is crucial to maintain full control of *what is a function of what*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

I must ask, though, why are your keeping $V$ constant on the third term?
What I mean is, why is $\frac{\partial \mathscr{Z}}{\partial T}=\left(\frac{\partial \mathscr{Z}}{\partial f}\right)_{V,T}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial T}\right)_{V,\mu}$ instead of simply $\frac{\partial \mathscr{Z}}{\partial T}=\left(\frac{\partial \mathscr{Z}}{\partial f}\right)_{T}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial T}\right)_{\mu}$, or even not keeping any of the variables $V, \mu, T$ constant at all?

Comment: @HGCMF For a function of many variables, the partial derivative with respect to one variable always implies that the other variables are kept constant. So, stressing with the notation that they are kept constant is redundant. However, in thermodynamics, physicists are used to indicating with the same symbol a function and the same function of other variables. In such a case, it is helpful to use a notation making explicit what are the independent variables. The alternative of not indicating the fixed variables would make impossible to evaluate the partial derivatives.

Comment: I see. I'm trying to wrap my head around working with this kind of derivatives, I'm sorry for the excessive questions.
I still can't see how that last formula would be solved. I tried solving it but came back empty handed. For the derivative $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\frac{PV}{kT}\right)_{V,\mu}$ (where $\ln \mathscr{Z}=PV/kT$) and which may be rewritten as $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\frac{PV\mu}{(kT)^2\ln(\lambda^3(T)n(N,V))}\right)_{V,\mu}$, am I supposed to take any other non-constant (apart from $\mu$ and $V$) as functions of T? For example as $P(T)=NkT/V$

Comment: @HGCMF, $P=NkT/V$, is specific for a perfect gas. The formulas you are trying to derive are completely general. I'll add a few more details to my answer.